# Deseo hacer un condicional para validar si lo que escribe un usuario contiene caracteres alfanuméricos o numéricos

Tags: php, postgresql

Bien, la idea del código que estoy desarrollando consiste en realizar una búsqueda a una base de datos Postgres desde un input en la web. En esa barra de búsqueda, la consulta puede ser alfanumérica o numérica.
Si es alfanumérica ejecuto una consulta en los campos de tipo varchar ejem.nombre, apellido, etc.
Pero si por el contrario el usuario ingresó una consulta numérica hago una consulta en la misma tabla pero en las columnas con datos de tipo numeric, o integer únicamente.

```php
if (!is_numeric( $_REQUEST['query_search'])){
    $query_search = pg_escape_string($db,ucwords($_REQUEST['query_search']));
    $where = "WHERE torre LIKE '%$query_search%' 
    OR nombre_estado LIKE '%$query_search%'
    OR nombre_municipio LIKE '%$query_search%'
    OR nombre_parroquia LIKE '%$query_search%'
    OR nombre_urbanismo LIKE '%$query_search%'
    OR nombre_sector LIKE '%$query_search%'";
    }else{
    $query_search = pg_escape_string($db,$_REQUEST['query_search']);
    $query_search = str_replace('.', '', $query_search);
    $decimal     = str_replace(',', '.', $query_search);
    
    $integer = str_replace(',', '',$query_search);
    
    $where = "WHERE idvivienda = '$integer' OR
            precio = '$decimal' OR
            piso = '$integer' OR
            area = '$decimal' OR
            tipo = '$integer' OR
            nro_apto = '$integer' OR
            nro_habitacion = '$integer' ";
  }
```

Lo primero que hago es definir el if intentando validar la consulta, donde recibo la variable con el método REQUEST desde otro documento.
He estado probando con esta funcion is_numeric(), funciona con cadenas alfanuméricas y con números enteros sin problemas. Pero si al usuario se le ocurre buscar un numero como *12.458,46* deja de validarlo como numero y lo toma como string, y seguidamente mi consulta sql falla.

Cabe aclarar que el usuario escribe los números con notación en español (usando puntos para separar miles y comas para decimales), y en la BD el tipo de dato numeric es con notación en inglés (usando comas para separar miles, y punto para decimales) por lo tanto convierto los valores antes de buscarlo en BD. También noté que si el usuario busca un numero grande como *9.123.456* la conversión de valores que hago deja de funcionar.

Comment: Puedes echar mano de una función como https://gist.github.com/msng/1504235. Quizá te ayude esa o alguna otra similar, para transformar primero cualquier número que te pasen antes de empezar a trabajar con él.

Comment: Gracias Mr! Estaré echándole un vistazo